# Error receiving broadcast Intent on DownloadManager DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm getting following error when I try to get status of the downloaded file from the Android Download manager.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.purelightaudio.healer, PID: 24201
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.purelightaudio.healer (has extras) } in com.purelightaudio.healer.network.FileDownLoadService$1@3f6d991
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1132)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
       at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:122)
       at android.database.CursorWrapper.getInt(CursorWrapper.java:122)
       at android.app.DownloadManager$CursorTranslator.getLong(DownloadManager.java:1485)
       at android.app.DownloadManager$CursorTranslator.getInt(DownloadManager.java:1477)
       at com.purelightaudio.healer.network.FileDownLoadService.getDownloadStatus(FileDownLoadService.java:146)
       at com.purelightaudio.healer.network.FileDownLoadService.access$100(FileDownLoadService.java:31)
       at com.purelightaudio.healer.network.FileDownLoadService$1.onReceive(FileDownLoadService.java:230)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1122)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

And permission was granted to Read,Write Storage and access Network/Internat

```
private void downloadFile(String mediaTitle, final Track track, DownloadManager downloadManager, int downloadCount) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(track.getTrackUrl());
    folder = new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString() + MEDIA_FOLDER);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    Log.d("Track aa",folder.toString()+ track.getTrackName());

    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
            .setTitle(track.getTrackName())
            .setDescription(mediaTitle)
            .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(folder.toString(), track.getTrackName()));

    downloadMap.put(downloadReference,downloadCount);
}
```

Broadcast Receiver code.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //check if the broadcast message is for our enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        int position = downloadMap.get(referenceId);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
            if (getDownloadStatus(referenceId)) {
                callBack.onCompleteDownloadNext(position);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download Complete " + media.getTracks().get(position).getTrackName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Track Downloaded", folder.toString() + media.getTracks().get(position).getTrackName());
                Log.d("Track Downloaded", downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId).toString());
                dataBaseUtils.AddTrackLocalUrl(downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId).toString(), media.getTracks().get(position).getTrackId());
            } else {
            callBack.onErrorDownload(position);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Download Failed " + media.getTracks().get(position).getMediaTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               dataBaseUtils.AddTrackLocalUrl(Config.ERROR_DOWNLOAD,media.getTracks().get(position).getTrackId());
            }
        }
        Log.d("Track Download",intent.getAction());


        completeDownloadCount++;
        if (media.getTracks().size() == completeDownloadCount){
            callBack.onCompleteDownload(platListId!=0?String.valueOf(platListId):null);
        }
    }
};
```

Download Status code

```
/**
 * Get File Download Status from the Download reference
 * @return isSuccessful download boolean
 * @param referenceId
 */
private boolean getDownloadStatus(long referenceId){

    DownloadManager.Query downloadQuery = new DownloadManager.Query();
    //set the query filter to our previously Enqueued download
    downloadQuery.setFilterById(referenceId);

    //Query the download manager about downloads that have been requested.
    Cursor cursor = ((DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).query(downloadQuery);
    //column for download  status
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    //column for reason code if the download failed or paused
    int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
    int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

    String statusText = "";
    String reasonText = "";
    boolean isSuccessful = false;

    switch(status){
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
            statusText = "STATUS_FAILED";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
            statusText = "STATUS_PAUSED";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
            statusText = "STATUS_PENDING";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
            statusText = "STATUS_RUNNING";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
            isSuccessful = true;
            statusText = "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL";
            break;
    return isSuccessful;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

> act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.purelightaudio.healer (has extras) } in com.purelightaudio.healer.network.FileDownLoadService$1@3f6d991 at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1132) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) **Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460) at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136) at**

My bet is that the call:
intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1); should be
intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0L);

Or you should handle the default-value of getLongExtra() before going to get the position, like:

```
long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
if(referenceId == -1)
   return;
int position = downloadMap.get(referenceId);
```

I recommend also to check out this blog: http://jhshi.me/2013/12/02/how-to-use-downloadmanager/index.html for details regarding Downloadmanager.